# Django model object with dynamically added attributes

Tags: python, django, model, django-templates

I'm looking for a way to dynamically add extra attributes to django model instances so that they are accessible in the template

For example,

in models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

in views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    f = Foo.objects.get(id=1234)

    # method in question
    f.____add_extra_attribute____('extra_attribute', attr_value)

    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'foo_instance':f})
```

in my_template.html

```
<h1>{{ foo_instance.name }}</h1>
<p>{{ foo_instance.extra_attribute }}</p>
```

is there a way to accomplish this without rendering the instance as a dictionary instead of a Foo model object?

Comment: maybe this is a stupid question, but why do you want it to be attached to the model at all?  Why not:  `render(request, 'my_template.html', {'foo_instance': f, 'extra_data': ...})`?

Comment: @mgilson When it is a list of instances, it may be needed

Comment: I'd avoid adding dynamic attributes to models. I was just facing a similar issue, and in my case I just added a model method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @mgilson's comment, you can pass the `extra_attribute` to the template in a *separate context variable*:

```
def my_view(request):
    f = Foo.objects.get(id=1234)
    extra_attribute = attr_value
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', 
                  {'foo_instance': f, 'extra_attribute': attr_value})
```

If you still want to set the attribute on a model instance, you can set it directly:

```
f.extra_attribute = attr_value
```

Comment: No need for `setattr` unless the name itself is dynamic. `f.extra_attribute = attr_value` works fine.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could dynamically give python objects new attributes. I need the attribute on the model instance because it is data associated with that instance, but I don't want it saved in the database or calculated for every object. Although I think this violates MVC, so it might be better to include it as a @property on the Foo class

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example below. This is real code from my project. Here I have attached an attribute to the model object itself.

My model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    report = models.ForeignKey(UtilizationReport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    billable_efforts = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(1.0)],
        )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    reviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In view.py:

```
task = Task.objects.get(id=1) # Just an example...won't be really using get with id
task_rate = BillingCatagoryRate.objects.get(rate_card=invoice.rate_card, billing_category=task.assignee.billing_category).billing_rate
task.task_price = task_rate * task.billable_efforts # Note: task_price is NOT a model field.
```

In the template:

```
<td class="text-center">{{ task.task_price }}</td>
```